# How to compare two groups for the same construct, measured by two different questionnaires within each group?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I’d like to compare two randomized (independent) patient groups regarding quality of life.

The challenge is that each of these two groups comprises patients having two clinical diagnoses. For each diagnosis, there is a disease-specific validated questionnaire available which needs to be applied to assess quality of life. Both questionnaires have the same range of values of the final score, the same scale direction (higher scores = better quality of life), were developed by the same research group, and, as pointed out, measure the same construct.

What kind of inferential test would be suitable to compare these two groups regarding quality of life given the conditions above? A t-test for independent samples would require merging the scores coming from the questionnaires into a single variable and use it for a between groups comparison. Is that feasible or is there a better option? Group size will be well beyond n > 30 each, so the assumption of normally distributed sample characteristics should not be an issue.